# code gets errors when passed an empty array

Tags: ruby

My code runs fine but gets errors when passed an empty array. I understand why but don't know how to fix it.

```
def format_comma_and(array)

  output =""

  if array.empty?
    return output
  else
     array.each.with_index do |x,i|
        if array.length-2 == i
          output << x + " and "
        elsif array.length-1 == i
          output << x
        else
          output << x + ", "
        end
     end
  return output
 end

end
```

Comment: What errors do you get, chief? This code returns an empty string when the array is empty, so it's probably the code that is calling this method that has the problem, yo.

Comment: sorry. undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: its for a challenge on codewars. it passes all the tests but doesnt final submit because of this error

Comment: You should add a couple things to this question: the line of code where the error occurred (you could just paste the full error) and the specific value you're passing into your function

Comment: It sounds like the array is not really empty, or that the error is not coming from this method. The error is saying that you're trying to use the `+` operator with something that is `nil`. As stated in the comment above, you should specify which line number the error is occurring on, and make sure that line of code is in your question and include the value you pass to the method when it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add "comma_and" this way :

```
   def format_comma_and(a = [])
     a[0...-1].any? ? a[0...-1] * ',' + " and #{a[-1]}" : "#{a[-1]}"
   end
```

Comment: This is certainly the most concise of the bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple just add a default value for the argument for the method at the top `format_comma_and(array=[])`, if lets say the method is called with no parameter. (i.e. `format_comma_and()`) then nil is sent to your method which can then cause an error like this, so as long as there is a default value this shouldn't happen:

```
def format_comma_and(array=[])

  output =""

  if array.empty?
    return output
  else
     array.each.with_index do |x,i|
        if array.length-2 == i
          output << x + " and "
        elsif array.length-1 == i
          output << x
        else
          output << x + ", "
        end
     end
  return output
 end

end
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
def format_comma_and(array=[])
return "" if array.size < 1
return "#{array[0]}" if array.size == 1
array[0..-2].join(", ") + " and #{array[-1]}"
end


format_comma_and([1,2,3,4])
#=> "1, 2, 3 and 4"
format_comma_and([1,2,3])
#=> "1, 2 and 3"
format_comma_and([1,2])
#=> "1 and 2"
format_comma_and([1])
#=> "1"
format_comma_and([])
#=> ""
format_comma_and()
#=> ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code and it does not raise an error when it is passed an empty array.

However, it will raise an error if you pass the following argument: `[nil]`.

`each_with_index` operates on each element of the array. If the first element is `nil` (this is different than the array being empty), then 
your code attempts to call `output = nil + " and "`

A quick fix would be to call `compact` on your array, i.e. put the following at the top of the method:

```
array = array.compact
```

This will remove all nil values.

Or you could filter your array to get rid of any invalid elements. I'm not sure what your instructions are, but see the following example:

```
array = [ nil, false, "string", 111, {}, [] ]
array = array.select { |item| [String, Integer].include?(item.class) }
array == ["string", 111] # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you really want to write something like this:

```
def format_comma_and(array)
  return if array.empty?
  *head, tail = array
  [head.join(", "), tail].join(" and ")
end
format_comma_and([1,2,3,4,5])
#=> "1, 2, 3, 4 and 5"
format_comma_and([1,2])
#=> "1 and 2"
format_comma_and([])
#=> nil
```

Comment: Just to note, if you run `format_comma_and([1])` , you get `" and 1"`, which might not be ideal if the kata is just expecting `"1"`.